# is there a simple way i can convert this list into a dictionary (python)

Tags: python-3.x

the list is this :

```
List1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','h','i','j','k','l','m','n']
```

And I am  hoping for the outcome to be where each times the item appears in the list its assigned an integer e.g:

```
List1 = ['a:1']
```

without using the  'import counter' module

Comment: `d = {}; for ch in List1: d[ch] = d.get(ch, 0) + 1` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this list comprehension:

```
dict((x, List1.count(x)) for x in set(List1))
```

Example output:

```
{'d': 1, 'f': 1, 'l': 1, 'c': 1, 'j': 1, 'e': 1, 'i': 1, 'a': 1, 'h': 2, 'b': 1, 'm': 1, 'n': 1, 'k': 1, 'g': 1}
```

Comment: is there anyway to change the value its assigned because right now its been assigned "enter the counter here"

Comment: If you want to modify values of each item in the dict, you can do the following: `dict((x, List1.count(x) * 2) for x in set(List1))` (this will multiply every value in the dict by 2).

Answer (score 0):

(Edited to match edited question.)
Use a dictionary comprehension and `count`.

```
>>> List1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','h','i','j','k','l','m','n']
>>> mapping = {v: List1.count(v) for v in List1}
>>> mapping
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'f': 1,
'g': 1, 'h': 2, 'i': 1, 'j': 1, 'k': 1, 'l': 1, 'm': 1, 'n': 1}
```

Comment: He wants the number of times each element appears.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that change :)